# Different methods of auth for presence/private channels using pusher

Tags: authentication, pusher

I am making a application where there is a presence channel for chat, and one private channel for admins, so their authentication process must be different, but there is no documentation on how to use different authentication methods for presence and private methods.

The documentation: http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authentication endpoint that receives the HTTP authentication request will receive the `channel_name` as a parameter of the request. You can use this (e.g. `channelName.startsWith('presence-')`) when determining which type of authentication you want to perform on the user.

If you know the type of user you are authenticating (via session or URL) when you generate the page then you can set the auth endpoint. It is also possible to change the authentication endpoint that is used to authenticate a user.  See: http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#authendpoint-smallstringsmall

Which solution you use depends on your application.

Comment: Thanks! I ended using your first solution, checking the channel-name parameter.